# In R, how can I create plots contained within a "matrix" or "dataframe" setting with row names and column names?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create a 3x3 grid of plots such each "cell" contains two plots. I am hoping to have each column name have two sub-column names (in this case "True"/"False"):

```
      ColumnName1      ColumnName2     ColumnName3
      True   | False   True   | False  True   | False
Row1  (plot) | (plot)  (plot) |(plot)  (plot) |(plot)
Row2  (plot) | (plot)  (plot) |(plot)  (plot) |(plot)
Row3  (plot) | (plot)  (plot) |(plot)  (plot) |(plot)
```

In the row 1, column 1 cell (Row 1, ColumnName1), two plots side by side correspond to a True condition and one to a False condition. An example of a cell would be

[image]

Is there a straightforward way or a package I can use to create such a "table" of plots with row names, column names, and the sub column dividers? Thanks!

Comment: Your basic data frame can do this. If you include an example starting point, we can show you.

Comment: Are you looking of something like [facet_grid and facet_wrap on ggplot2]( http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-facet-split-a-plot-into-a-matrix-of-panels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach. This is a 3 x 6 layout since each graph has its own y-axis:

```
dev.new(width=12, height=8)
layout(matrix(1:18, 3, 6, byrow=TRUE))
par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1))
for(i in 1:18) {plot(rnorm(10))}
```

[image: Plot]